# Centering clrscode3e codebox horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms

How can I center a `codebox` (from `clrscode3e` package) horizontally in a document ?

Comment: The width of the `codebox` is variable. Thus strictly "centering" is not possible. You could only increase the left margin to move it to the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `codebox` is ultimately typeset in a `tabbing` environment, its width may vary. Moreover, it is typeset in a box which is only processed at the end of the `codebox` environment. As such, you would need a slight work-around in order to center it horizontally.

The [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) is capable of shrinking its width to the natural width of its contents. As such, wrapping the `codebox` environment within a `varwidth` environment allows for centering capability:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{clrscode3e}% http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{codebox}
      \Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
      \li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
      \li \Do $\id{key} \gets A[j]$
      \li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence $A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
      \li $i \gets j-1$
      \li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
      \li \Do
            $A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
      \li $i \gets i-1$
          \End
      \li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
      \End
    \end{codebox}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The `varwidth` environment is set to the maximum (`\linewidth`), since it will shrink to the desired width if the `codebox` is not as wide.

The `showframe` option to [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) allows for a visual of the text block boundaries.

---

My original approach was to use the `savepos` module of the [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) to mark the left-most and right-most points in the code via the macro `\zsavepos{<label>}`. Then, using `\zposx{<ref>}`, one can extract the x-coordinate (in small point `sp` units) of the label. So, marking the left-most point using `\zsavepos{codeL}` and the right-most point using `\zsavepos{codeR}`,

```
\dimexpr\zposx{codeR}sp-\zposx{codeL}sp\relax
```

gives the horizontal width (or dimension) of the `codebox`. Subsequently, putting the entire `codebox` environment in a `minipage` of this width allows us to constrain the horizontal span and center the object. The correct width also avoids overfull `\hbox` warnings (if a chosen `minipage` width is too small) or incorrect centering (if a chosen `minipage` width is too large).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{clrscode3e}% http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\zposx{codeR}sp-\zposx{codeL}sp\relax}
    \begin{codebox}
      \Procname{\zsavepos{codeL}$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
      \li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
      \li \Do $\id{key} \gets A[j]$
      \li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence $A[1 \twodots j-1]$.\zsavepos{codeR}
      \li $i \gets j-1$
      \li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
      \li \Do
            $A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
      \li $i \gets i-1$
          \End
      \li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
      \End
    \end{codebox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The above code (or procedure) was taken directly from the [`clrscode3e` package](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Ethc/clrscode/) [documentation](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Ethc/clrscode/clrscode3e.pdf). The right-most label depends on the code segment being typeset, while the left-most label is typeset to the left of the procedure name. However, it is not necessary for the final production and centering capabilities. Since this uses the `zref` package, at least two compiles are required to obtain the correct positioning of the labels/references.

Comment: `zref` is overkill. It is possible to use `varwidth` environment instead of `minipage` to write `codebox`. Then it can be centered as a wide box. However, I still think it is better to indent but not center it.

Comment: @LeoLiu: I'm following the OP's request for centering, but why would `zref` be overkill? `varwidth` is only capable of *shrinking* to some natural width, which in this case is set by `tabbing` for indenting purposes. In fact, `tabbing` is set to be as wide as "two digits plus 9 `\textbf{else}`'s".

Comment: @LeoLiu: For some strange reason my original attempts with `varwidth` didn't work. However, you were right, and I've added it as a shorter alternative to centering the `codebox`.