# How to manage long lines of inputs in function declaration, or inside the code, in clrscode3e

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, algorithms

This is a part of my code:

```
\begin{codebox}

\Procname{$\proc{\textbf{Connect_two_SamplePoints}}(Graph,S1, S2,connectionCostMat,cost)$}
\li \Comment S1 and S2 are sample points 
\li  cost[S1][S2] $=$ $\infty$ 
\li \Comment  cost holds the length of shortest path between S1 and S2
\li \For $pnt$ in connectionCostMat[S1]: \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\Comment candidate point for S1
\li \> \For $pnt2$ in connectionCostMat[S2]:  \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\Comment candidate point for S2
\li \> \> \If shortestPathLength($pnt$,$pnt2$) $+$ connectionCostMat[$S1$][$pnt$] $+$ connectionCostMat[$S2$][$pnt2$]< cost[S1][S2]:
\li \Then \> \> cost[S1][S2] $=$ shortestPathLength($pnt$,$pnt2$) $+$ connectionCostMat[$S1$][$pnt$] $+$ connectionCostMat[$S2$][$pnt2$] \End

\end{codebox}
```

You can see how long the name of the function is, as well as few line in the actual code. Using the default settings of `clrscode3e`, I get an ugly set of code, with function inputs and lines in code extended all the way to the margin and disappeared... pretty awful.
I tried [Centering clrscode3e codebox horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36762/centering-clrscode3e-codebox-horizontally), but it didn't make things better.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to this package, but perhaps the following may be close to what you're after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clrscode3e}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{ConnectTwoSamplePoints}(Graph, S1, S2, connectionCostMat, cost)$}
\li  cost[S1][S2] $= \infty$
\li \Comment  cost holds the length of the shortest path between S1 and S2
\li \For $pnt$ in connectionCostMat[S1]: \Comment candidate point for S1
\li \For $pnt2$ in connectionCostMat[S2]: \Comment candidate point for S2
\li \If shortestPathLength($pnt , pnt2$) +
\\ \quad connectionCostMat[$S1$][$pnt$] +
\\ \quad connectionCostMat[$S2$][$pnt2$] \textless cost[S1][S2]
\li \Then cost[S1][S2] $=$ shortestPathLength($pnt$,$pnt2$) +
\\  \quad \quad \quad connectionCostMat[$S1$][$pnt$] +
\\ \quad \quad \quad connectionCostMat[$S2$][$pnt2$]
\End
\end{codebox}

\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

This package isn't on my (recent) CTAN so I used the `.sty` file from [here](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/clrscode3e.sty).

Problems I encountered:

1. Underscore (i.e. "`_`") doesn't seem to play well with `\Procname` - hopefully this is not essential...
2. Need to use `\\` to force newline. I've done this manually as it appears that the package isn't designed to cope with such long lines of code.
3. Explict `\Then` has been [deprecated](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/clrscode3e.pdf) and appears it's been replaced with a `\quad` spacing.
4. Manually insert `\quad` spacing to have the text line up as expected.

I'm not sure this package is ideally suited to presenting the type of code you have in mind...

Comment: i don't think we've ever had `clrscode3e` on ctan.  `clrscode` _ought_ to be appropriate, given the nature of the book it was written for... ;-)